# Plot random numbers on y, x is the range

Tags: r, plot

I want to generate 50 random values in the range 0-180. What I did:

```
a=runif(50,min=0,max=180)
```

Now I want this plot: x axis is the range from 0-180, y axis is just a single value (1), showing a dot where the 0-180 number exists in the "a" set, nothing if it doesn't.

Do I need to generate numbers 0-180 for the x axis, or can R do it with only the "a" set? If I do `plot(a)`, I get a scatter plot where x is the index and y is the value.

[image: img]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something resembling the example closely, here it is:

```
x <- runif(50, 0, 180)

# make an empty plot
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = c(0,185), ylim = c(0,2), xaxs = "i")

# add grid lines
abline(h = 1, col = "gray", lwd = 2)
abline(v = c(0,90,180), col = "gray", lwd = 2)

# add points
points(x, rep(1, length(x)), pch = 19, cex = 1.5)

# add axes
axis(1, at = c(0,90,180), font = 2, cex.axis = 2, tck = 0)
box(bty = "L", lwd = 3)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks, the code is longer than the other answer, but it recreates the look, too :)

Answer (score 3):

First prepare an empty plot:

```
plot(c(0,180),c(1,1),type="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
```

(The `type="n"` parameter makes sure nothing is plotted. We suppress the vertical axis using `yaxt="n"`.)

Then add the points at a constant $y$ value of 1:

```
points(a,rep(1,length(a)),pch=19)
```

[image: dots]

Of course, the aspect ratio can be improved (most easily by specifying the height and width when you open a graphics device, e.g., using `png()`, which you need to close using `dev.off()` when you are done plotting). And we could change the whitespace around the plot; look at `?par`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly how close to the given example you want it, the code can be quite simple. For example

```
dev.new(width=5, height=3)
stripchart(a, pch=16, xaxp=c(0, 180, 2), xlim=c(0, 180), xaxs="i")
grid(nx=4, ny=2, col="#00000044", lty=1)
```

gives

[image]

Using `stripchart()` as the basis can be smart in case you want to compare multiple samples. For example:

```
set.seed(1)
l <- list(a=a, b=runif(10, min=60, max=240))
dev.new(width=5, height=3)
stripchart(l, pch=16, xaxp=c(0, 240, 4), xlim=c(0, 240), ylim=c(0.5, 2.5), xaxs="i")
abline(v=seq.int(0, 240, length.out=5), col="#00000044")
abline(h=1:2, col="#00000044")
```

[image]